# System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I am doing client server project in winforms using C#. Client requests for files in a particular date. client running in windows 7 32 bit system, and server running in windows server 2008 R2.

This code is in my client converting datetime value into string.

```
string date = dateTimePickerFrom.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is the code used in server to get back the Datetime value from the string

```
string dat = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb.ReadBytes(len));
FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dat, "dd/MM/yyy HH:MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Am getting "System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.    at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)" this error in server side. How to solve this? Any help please.

Comment: What type of data is used on the sqlserver date or datetime I think DateTime.ParseExact takes only 3 parameters

Comment: How are you sending it ?

Comment: Just to be sure, check what `dat` contains just before executing the last line of code (`ParseExact`). Also, check to see if you can do those conversions without any servers, etc. Pick a date, convert to string, convert back to date, and see if it works.

Comment: I think the encoding is wrong which is resulting in some invalid characters and fail for the parse,  can you check doing it via Unicode since .Net strings are in unicode.

Comment: What makes you think the string is in ASCII? I think it's more likely it's unicode or UTF. I would use the `GetEncoding` method to verify the strings encoding before attempting a conversion. Even if it is in ASCII, the code would be more robust if you performed a check prior to conversion.

Comment: Did anyone point out that you used `HH:MM` instead of `HH:mm`? I assume you want minutes, not months?

Answer (score 2):

Your ParseExact() format looks like
`dd/MM/yyy HH:MM` and should be `dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM`.

Answer (score 0):

why do you convert twice between a datetime value and a string?
on the client side, a datatime value to string, and then send the string to server.
on the server side, you get the string, and convert it back to datetime.
why do you do these convertions? datetime->string->datetime, it make nonsense.  
you should send datetime directly to the server, and the get the datetime directly. i guess you are using socket to do this.
don't let string bother you.
the code as bellow:

```
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        long l0 = now.ToBinary();
        byte [] array = BitConverter.GetBytes(l0);
        //here you can send it to the server

        //on the server
        byte[] buffer = null;  //receive bytes 
        long l1 = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer,0);
        DateTime time = DateTime.FromBinary(l1);
```

Comment: i am not a native english speaker, i am not sure whether i make it clear. THAT IS, you SHOULD NOT use string AT ALL. date -> string -> date, what you need is a date, nothing about string.

Comment: Is it possible to convert datetime into byte?

Comment: actually, datetime IS saved as a long data type, which is actually 4 bytes. so , we can get a long value by DateTime.ToBinary(), and use BitConvertor class to get 4 bytes. as the code i posted shows

Comment: Am using byte[] array to send datas over TCP connection. So am using this conversion Datetime--> string --> byte[] in client and getting back in server byte[] --> string --> datetime.

Comment: i try and get back to you soon

Comment: I know that.  You should send DateTime directly by tcp. No matter you send string or datetime or any type else, you must convert it to byte[] first. But the string here is not necessary, and may generate errors, just like it does now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
long longVar = BitConverter.ToInt64(bb.ReadBytes(len));
DateTime dateTimeVar = new DateTime(1980,1,1).AddMilliseconds(longVar);
```